# How to get time information on XBee S2C?

Tags: xbee

On my project, I'm using XBeeS2C+Digispark and connect each other as Serial communication(UART). I'm using SoftSerial on Digispark to set XBee. I have 1 coordinator and 3 routers in the same network. 
Now I'm trying to tell routers the coordinator time.  I don't now well how can I get time information(year, month, day, hour etc..) using XBee. Is it possible to get time information from Coordinator? 
Or should I use RTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XBee hardware does not keep track of date/time.  You could have a single device on your network use an RTC or some other connection (maybe a gateway with Ethernet/Wi-Fi connectivity to the Internet?) to track time and broadcast that information to the other devices periodically.